# An error occurs when using MongoDB adapter and NextAuth - importsNotUsedAsValues is deprecated

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next-auth

I use mongodb-adapter with Next Auth. Since yesterday I get the following error message in the nodeModules in the MongoDB folder within tsconfig.json and the application is not running.

> Option 'importsNotUsedAsValues' is deprecated and will stop functioning in TypeScript 5.5. Specify compilerOption '"ignoreDeprecations": "5.0"' to silence this error.
> Use 'verbatimModuleSyntax' instead.

this is the tsconfig.json file in mongodb folder:

```
 {
"compilerOptions": {
//Also not work with this line
//"ignoreDeprecations": "5.0",
"allowJs": false,
"checkJs": false,
"strict": true,
"alwaysStrict": true,
"target": "ES2020",
"module": "commonJS",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"skipLibCheck": true,
"lib": [
  "es2020"
],
// We don't make use of tslib helpers, all syntax used is supported by target engine
"importHelpers": false,
"noEmitHelpers": true,
// Never emit error filled code
"noEmitOnError": true,
"outDir": "lib",

//###########
//Also tried, but not work
//"verbatimModuleSyntax":true,
"importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
//###########

// We want the sourcemaps in a separate file
"inlineSourceMap": false,
"sourceMap": true,
// API-Extractor uses declaration maps to report problems in source, no need to distribute
"declaration": true,
"declarationMap": true,
// we include sources in the release
"inlineSources": false,
// Prevents web types from being suggested by vscode.
"types": [
  "node"
],
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"noImplicitOverride": true,
"noImplicitReturns": true,
// TODO(NODE-3659): Enable useUnknownInCatchVariables and add type assertions or remove 
unnecessary catch blocks
"useUnknownInCatchVariables": false
},
"ts-node": {
"transpileOnly": true,
 "compiler": "typescript-cached-transpile"
},
"include": [
 "src/**/*"
 ]
}
```